# Test whether value is within column using BigQuery, stop at first match

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to test whether a column contains a particular value, and stop at the first match if true.

Currently I'm using:

```
select count(*) from <table> where <column> = <value>
```

And then testing whether the return value is zero or non-zero. But if there are a few million rows, and the value is at the first row, this query will still process all of the rows.

I found something that uses `TOP`, but that command doesn't seem to be available in big query. I also tried `LIMIT`, but  this processes the same about of data, just truncates the return value.

I'm expecting an operation with a similar behaviour to that of `any( )` in python, which will stop as soon as there's a match rather than checking through all values of the iterable.

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery is a parallel database that is running many threads at the same time.  In general, I would recommend writing the query as:

```
select 1
from <table>
where <column> = <value>
limit 1;
```

This will not incur additional overhead for aggregation -- which could be significant if there are many duplicate values in the table.

However, the two queries will probably have similar durations.  BigQuery is not the best database for "finding needles in haystacks".  It is designed for processing massive amounts of data.

Comment: thanks, as far as I can tell this will process the same amount of data as what I initially posted though? So I guess this is general query advice rather than a solution. Re your comment about finding needles, perhaps in this case there's not a solution? I assumed it would be, if i have to process the whole column then I will though I guess

Comment: @baxx . . . You will be *charged* for all the data in the table.  There is no way around that unless you are using partitions.  How much is actually read is a different matter.

Comment: thank you, it's a bit confusing as I don't know if I know enough to close the question, given that I wanted something that would stop at first match, resulting in less data being processed by a particular query. If there's any information that I can add or whatever I will try to, perhaps it should be clear from your response that this isn't possible and I'm just missing the point

Comment: @baxx . . . The data being charged is determined *before* the query is run.

Comment: ok sure - but if I am able to be process less, then regardless of the charge, it might be quicker for the user, and that remains a question to be answered. Though knowing that regardless of the amount fo data processed the charge is the same is useful information, so thank you

Answer (score 1):

If the the goal here is to reduce "data processed", in BigQuery, approaches that might work are:

- Partitioning the table by `column`, or
- Clustering the table by `column`, or
- (if the table has a lot of duplicate) create a materialized view on the side and try to query that view, like

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW AS 
SELECT distinct <column> FROM <table>
```